# Change content of Text element React

Tags: javascript, text, react-native

This seems so basic but I can't figure out to do it, and it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. I've got a text element in my react page

```
<Text ref="WarningText"
                  style={loginStyle.warningLabel}>{this.warningText}</Text>
```

And I want to change the content of this Text element. Changing `this.warningText` doesn't help nor does calling `this.refs.WarningText.setNativeProps({text: text});` or changing any other propname that I could come up with.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use state instead of refs or anything else. That's Reacts design pattern.

```
<Text style={loginStyle.warningLabel}>{this.state.warningText}</Text>
```

and in your event you can change the text by chnaging the state and react automatically updates your text.

```
this.setState({warningText: "some text"})
```

Here's some more [documentation on setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). It gives most of the ins and outs of how to use and not use state in your components.

Comment: quick question, do you have to explicitly define all your "state" parameters on a setState({...}) call, or will the undefined values be left alone in the GUI?

Comment: @DaanLuttik they will be left alone

Comment: As @FuzzyTree said they will be left alone. A better design pattern for handling your states and stuff in general is using Redux. You might wanna check that out too.

Comment: If you're interested in storing state in Redux, Egghead.io had [a great getting started course by the author of Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) that would help you along that direction.